# D3 Domain Values Go Over Range

Tags: d3.js

I am working with D3 to try and create a simple bar chart. My x-axis uses ScaleTime and my y-axis uses ScaleLinear. In the pictures below, you can see that the values I've put for the domain (date values) go past the the range. Shouldn't the ticks be confined to the line? Been struggling with this for a while and haven't been able to find anything on the internet.

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhpzO.png)

[Inspect Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8K7I3.png)

EDIT

After applying .clamp, this is the result

[New Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1edZa.png)

And here is the main part of my code I'm looking at (some of the values are arbitrary)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydI7W.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please always post code as text rather than an image/screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because [clamping is disabled](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/main/README.md#scaleTime) by default on time scales:

> Constructs a new time scale with the specified domain and range, the default interpolator and clamping disabled.

It's hard to suggest a fix without seeing your code, but try something like [this](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-scaletime#cell-751):

```
d3.scaleTime()
   .domain([domain)
   .range([range])
   .clamp(true)(Date.now())
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The clamp function did work to shorten the 'g' element, but the values are scrunched up at the end. I'll edit the post to show code and the new result.

Comment: I think you only need to pass an array with two elements into the .domain() function. try use [d3.extent](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#extent) to get the min/max of the dates as an array and pass that to domain instead.